# How to type the file path in FileReader r = new FileReader("How to get the file path");

Tags: java, exception, filereader, filenotfoundexception

I am unable to to understand how to write the file name. Because it always shows FileNotFoundException.

I have a file named topnote.txt made on IntelliJ. But it is not found even if I am putting the path of file.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Can you please add the relevant component of your code?

Answer (score 1):

Execute the following to know where the application root resides, then refer the file relative to the location:

```
System.out.println(new java.io.File("test-file-name-this-wont-be-created").getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: I get that, but the problem is it cannot locate it at all.